# Issue with select query: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing issues while exeucting the below query  as "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string". Not able to identify the actual issue.

```
select
  *
from(
    select
      a.*,
      rownum rnum
    from(
        SELECT
          E1."BAMEVENT" AS "BAMEVENT",
          E1."BCRMORDERID" AS "BCRMORDERID",
          E1."COMPLETIONTIME" AS "COMPLETIONTIME",
          E1."CONTACT" AS "CONTACT",
          E1."CREATIONTIME" AS "CREATIONTIME",
          E1."CURRENTOWNERID" AS "CURRENTOWNERID",
          E1."CURRENTOWNERNAME" AS "CURRENTOWNERNAME",
          E1."CUSTOMERNAME" AS "CUSTOMERNAME",
          E1."CUSTOMERSEGMENT" AS "CUSTOMERSEGMENT",
          E1."CUSTOMERSUBSEGMENT" AS "CUSTOMERSUBSEGMENT",
          E1."CUSTOMERID" AS "CUSTOMERID",
          E1."CUSTOMERREGION" AS "CUSTOMERREGION",
          E1."ESCLATIONLEVELFIRED" AS "ESCALATIONLEVELFIRED",
          E1."ESTIMATECOMPLETIONDATE" AS "ESTIMATECOMPLETETIME",
          E1."OVERALLESTIMATECOMPLETIONDATE" AS "ESTIMATEDCLOSUREDATE",
          E1."EVENTTYPE" AS "EVENTTYPE",
          E1."EVENTWEIGHT" AS "EVENTWEIGHT",
          E1."MODIFIEDBY" AS "MODIFIEDBY",
          E1."MODIFIEDDATE" AS "MODIFIEDDATE",
          E1."ORDERNUMBER" AS "ORDERNUMBER",
          E1."ORDERSTATUS" AS "ORDERSTATUS",
          E1."OWNER" AS "OWNER",
          E1."PARTYID" AS "PARTYID",
          E1."PARTYNAME" AS "PARTYNAME",
          E1."PROCESSINSTANCEID" AS "PROCESSINSTANCEID",
          E1."PRODUCTDESC" AS "PRODUCTDESCRIPTION",
          E1."PRODUCTOFFERINGNAME" AS "PRODUCTOFFERING",
          E1."REQUESTID" AS "REQUESTID",
          E1."REQUESTEDDATE" AS "REQUESTEDDATE",
          E1."REQUESTEDSYSTEM" AS "REQUESTEDSYSTEM",
          E1."REVERSALREASON" AS "REVERSALREASON",
          E1."SLABREACHED" AS "SLABREACHED",
          E1."SMARTSEARCH" AS "SMARTSEARCH",
          E1."TICKETNUMBER" AS "TICKETNUMBER",
          E1."TRANSACTIONID" AS "TRANSACTIONID",
          E1."PRODUCTIDENTIFIER" AS "PRODUCTIDENTIFIER",
          C2."BUSINESSSEGMENT" AS "BUSINESSSEGMENT",
          E1."PRODUCTIDENTIFIER" AS "COLUMN",
          E1."ORDERCHANNEL" AS "ORDERCHANNEL",
          E1."OVERALLPROGRESSPRCNT" AS "OVERALLPROGRESSPRCNT",
          E1."PROCESSINSTANCEPRCNT" AS "PROCESSINSTANCEPRCNT",
          O3."BCRMREQUESTTYPE" AS "BCRMREQUESTTYPE",
          O3."OPRODUCTDETAIL_PRODUCTCATEGORY" AS "OPRODUCTDETAILPRODUCTCATEGOR",
          O3."OPRODUCTDETAIL_PRODUCTLINE" AS "OPRODUCTDETAILPRODUCTLINE",
          O3."OPRODUCTDETAIL_PRODUCTOFFERING" AS "OPRODUCTDETAILPRODUCTOFFERIN",
          R4."CBCMREQUESTTYPE" AS "CBCMREQUESTTYPE",
          R4."ORDERREFERENCENUMBER" AS "ORDERREFERENCENUMBER"
        FROM
          "BAMSPAPP"."ETOE_ORDER_TRACKER" E1,
          "BAMSPAPP"."CUST_DETAILS" C2,
          "BAMSPAPP"."ORDER_LINE_ITEMS_DETAILS" O3,
          "BAMSPAPP"."REQUEST_DETAILS" R4
        WHERE
          (
            E1."PROCESSINSTANCEID" = C2."PROCESSINSTANCEID"(+)
          )
          AND (
            E1."PROCESSINSTANCEID" = O3."PROCESSINSTANCEID"(+)
          )
          AND (
            E1."PROCESSINSTANCEID" = R4."PROCESSINSTANCEID"(+)
          )
          AND E1.CREATIONTIME >= '2019-02-01T00:00:00'
          AND E1.CREATIONTIME < = '2019-05-06T00:00:00'
          AND (
            (
              (
                E1.ORDERSTATUS = 'Closed'
                or E1.ORDERSTATUS = 'Cancelled'
              )
              and E1.PRODUCTIDENTIFIER = 'Mobile'
              and NOT(E1.COMPLETIONTIME < SYSDATE -10)
            )
            OR (
              (
                E1.ORDERSTATUS = 'Closed'
                or E1.ORDERSTATUS = 'Cancelled'
              )
              and (
                E1.PRODUCTIDENTIFIER IS NULL
                or E1.PRODUCTIDENTIFIER != 'Mobile'
              )
              and NOT(E1.COMPLETIONTIME < SYSDATE -30)
            )
            OR (
              E1.ORDERSTATUS != 'Closed'
              and E1.ORDERSTATUS != 'Cancelled'
            )
          )
        order by
          E1.CREATIONTIME
      ) a
    where
      rownum <= 5000
  )
where
  rnum >= 0
```

Comment: Can you reduce the query to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem? Can you provide the data type for each of the fields used in that reduced query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from comparing dates with character strings. Assuming `CREATIONDATE` is a date type field (which it should be) then the error is in the following conditions in your `where` clause:

```
          E1.CREATIONTIME >= '2019-02-01T00:00:00'
      AND E1.CREATIONTIME < = '2019-05-06T00:00:00'
```

You can solve it as follows:

```
          E1.CREATIONTIME >= to_date('2019-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      AND E1.CREATIONTIME <= to_date('2019-05-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Or from Oracle 11g onwards:

```
          E1.CREATIONTIME >= date '2019-02-01'
      AND E1.CREATIONTIME <= date '2019-05-06'
```

If however, these fields are character strings (`varchar2`), then the problem will be with the following condition:

```
    NOT(E1.COMPLETIONTIME < SYSDATE -10)
```

Then you would need to fix it like this:

```
    NOT(to_date(E1.COMPLETIONTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') < SYSDATE -10)
```

...where the second argument passed to the `to_date` function must represent the exact format of the field's content.

Comment: NOT(E1.COMPLETIONTIME < SYSDATE -10) was the issue

Comment: That would only be an issue if `COMPLETIONTIME` is not a date but a varchar2 data type. You did not specify this, so I assumed that these were of date type, which is the best practice of course.

Comment: See addition to my answer for when your fields are `varchar2`.